# Как создать sql запрос between для атрибутов?

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице магазина через `get` параметр передаётся числовое значение выбранного атрибута, `$_GET['min_probeg']` и $_GET['max_probeg']`.
Сам атрибут товара в админке сохранён так: имя - от 100 км, слаг - ot-100-km, или ot-200-km.
Как создать запрос, наподобии такого?

```
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'          => '_price',
                'value'        => array($min, $max),
                'type'         => 'numeric',
                'compare'      => 'BETWEEN',
                'price_filter' => true,
            );
```

но только нужно сделать выборку среди атрибутов, а не среди мета-данных записи.
у параметров запроса `tax_query` нет параметра `compare`, для которого можно установить `between`.
Есть вариант, при сохранении товара, сохранять его атрибуты в качестве мета-данных, и тогда можно будет делать выборку с помощью `between`.
Есть ли вариант проще?

Answer (score 2):

```
$tax_query[] = 
'relation' => 'AND',
[
    'key'          => '_price',
    'value'        => $min,
    'type'         => 'numeric',
    'operator'     => '>=',
],
[
    'key'          => '_price',
    'value'        => $max,
    'type'         => 'numeric',
    'operator'     => '<=',
];
```